# Combinations backtracking problem. The resulted list is return with 0 elements

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations, backtracking

I am trying to understand backtracking and one of the problems would be this one:

*Given two integers n and k, return all possible combinations of k numbers chosen from the range [1, n].
You may return the answer in any order.*

In my exemple I am using n = 4, k = 2

```
IList<IList<int>> Combine(int n, int k)
{
    IList<IList<int>> list = new List<IList<int>>();
    IList<int> listComb = new List<int>();
    backtrack(1, n, k, list, listComb);

    return list;
}
void backtrack(int start,int end,int k,IList<IList<int>> list,IList<int> oneComb)
{
    if (oneComb.Count == k)
    {
        list.Add(oneComb);
        return;
    }

    for(int i= start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        oneComb.Add(i);
        backtrack(i + 1, end, k, list, oneComb);
        oneComb.RemoveAt(oneComb.Count-1);
    }


}

Combine(4, 2);
```

Why "list" has 6 elements(which is correct) but all of them are with 0 values.
If I tried to print the combinations they are correctly found but when it returns my list has 0 values.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what backtracking is trying to do?